# Alienware 14 (Mid 2013) Ubuntu 15.04 switch off lights

Tags: alienware, keyboard-backlight

I am a new Ubuntu user and have 15.04 version. I am wondering if there is any thing that I could do to switch off the lights of my keyboard (AlienFX).

I have already tried the two (I do not if is right call them software) *pyalienware* and *alienwarekbl*. However neither one or those work (perhaps I am doing something wrong). I can install them, but when I click on the icon to run the app it does not works. If there is other way to turn off the lights this would be great.

PS: Unfortunately I do not have Windows on this laptop. However with Ubuntu, until now, everything works well even better than Windows (when I had it installed at the time).

Answer (score 1):

You can install [pyAlienFX](https://code.google.com/p/pyalienfx/) and run it with sudo from console. I managed to turn off the lights that way.... but can't turn it on again without rebooting.

I've the Alienware m14x r1.